# Signup is not function, signup is undefined error React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I just purchased a course of React Native from Udemy, Stephen Grider is the author of the course. So basically I'm typing my code with him as he types. But unfortunately I'm stuck in a error in the signup process of track application. Whenever I click on Sign Up button after putting email and password so my screen shows this error. Please check my code if there is any mistake so please let me know.

**Error**

> signup is not a function. (In signup({    email: email,    password:
>   password })', 'signup' is undefined);

**Eror ScreenShot**

[image: Error Image]

**SignupScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Text, Button, Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import Spacer from '../components/Spacer';
import { Context as AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';

const SignupScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state, signup } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text h3 style={styles.heading}>Sign Up for Tracker</Text>
            <Input
                label='Email'
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
            />
            <Spacer />
            <Input
                secureTextEntry
                label='Password'
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
            />
            <Spacer />
            <Spacer>
                <Button
                    title="Sign Up"
                    onPress={() => signup({ email, password })}
                />
            </Spacer>
        </View>
    );
};

SignupScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        header: null
    };
};
export default SignupScreen;
```

**AutoContext.js**

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import trackerApi from '../api/tracker';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const signup = dispatch => {
    return async ({ email, password }) => {
        try {
            const response = await trackerApi.post('/signup', { email, password });
            console.log(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    };
};
const signin = dispatch => {
    return ({ email, password }) => {

    };
};
const signout = dispatch => {
    return ({ email, password }) => {

    };
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
    authReducer,
    { signin, signout, signup },
    { isSignedIn: false }
);
```

**createDataContext.js**

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = React.createContext();

    const Provider = ({ children }) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);
        const boundActions = {};
        for (let key in boundActions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    };
    return { Context, Provider };
};
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import TrackListScreen from './src/screens/TrackListScreen';
import TrackDetailScreen from './src/screens/TrackDetailScreen';
import TrackCreateScreen from './src/screens/TrackCreateScreen';
import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    trackListFlow: createStackNavigator({
      TrackList: TrackListScreen,
      TrackDetail: TrackDetailScreen
    }),
    TrackCreate: TrackCreateScreen,
    Account: AccountScreen
  })
});

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are defining your context content as coming from the `AuthContext` file but your filename is called `AutoContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake in my `createDataContext` file.

change this condition from

```
for (let key in boundActions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
```

to

```
  for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
```