# TypeError: signUp is not a function - React Native Redux Typo

Tags: function, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to learn the basics about redux and am taking a Udemy course. I am running into the same issue as the below post but I have reviewed my code a number of times and am not seeing any syntax errors. I was hoping someone could point out where I fat fingered the code.

[Signup is not function, signup is undefined error React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269188/signup-is-not-function-signup-is-undefined-error-react-native)

> signup is not a function. (In signup({ userName: userName, password: password })', 'signup' is undefined);

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'
import config from '../config';
import {Context as AuthContext} from '../context/AuthContext';

const LoginForm = ({navigation}) => {
    const { state, signup } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    loginSuccess = () => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
        navigation.navigate('mainFlow');
    };

    loginFailed = () => {
        setError('Login failure. Please try again.');
    };


    return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
        <TextInput placeholder = "username or email"
            placeholderTextColor= "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
            returnKeyType="next"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={userName}
            onChangeText={setUserName}
            style ={styles.input}/>
        <TextInput placeholder = "password"
            placeholderTextColor= "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
            returnKeyType="go"
            secureTextEntry
            value={password}
            onChangeText= {setPassword}
            style = {styles.input}/>
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=> signup({userName, password})}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}> 
                LOGIN 
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20
    },
    input: {
        height: 40, 
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        marginBottom: 15, 
        color: '#FFF',
        paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
        paddingVertical: 15
    },
    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontWeight: '700'
    },
    error : {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'red',
        fontFamily: 'Baskerville'
    }
});
export default LoginForm;
```

Note: I assume this is a typo because my code is the same as the tutorial and the above linked issue (other then her typo.

AuthContext. js
Note: config is my auth file to Firebase. I have tried to remove everything in `signup` and just console.log but I am unable to enter into the function.

```
import CreateDataContext from './CreateDataContext';
import config from '../config';

const authReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        default: 
            console.log('switch values: ' + state);
            return state;
    };
};

const signup = (dispatch) => {
    return async ({userName, password})=>{
    try{
        // make an api request to sign up with email and password
        const user = {
            userName: userName,
            password: password,
        };

        const response = config.loginViaRedux(user);
        // if sign up was successful , we want to modify our state telling it the user was authenticated
        console.log('response: ' + response.data);
    } catch(e){
        // if sign up fails, we need to show an error message
        console.log('response error: ' + e.message);
    }
    };
};

const signIn = (dispatch) => {
    return({email, password})=>{
    };
};

const signOut = (dispatch) => {
    return({email, password})=>{
    };
};

export const {Provider, Context} = CreateDataContext (
    authReducer,
    {},
    {isSignedIn: false}
);
```

Comment: Can you share the `AuthContext` file code

Comment: @fayeed I updated the post with the AuthContext file

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was missing the export of the methods.

I added:

```
export const {Provider, Context} = CreateDataContext (
    authReducer,
    {signIn, signOut, signup},
    {isSignedIn: false, errorMessage: ''}
);
```

and the method is now visible!